# Odoo restrict regular user

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Im having troubles restricting the analytic timesheet so that employees only can see and edit their own hours.

I tried restricting it with the rule [('user_id','=',user.id)] but I guess I entered the rule to the wrong place.

How exactly do I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Put your code so we can see what is wrong

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/c8TPu

The rule is active for the Employee group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule looks fine, but it needs to be "Apply on Read" also.

Currently, it's not applied on read, so users would be able to *view* all other employees' hours, but not create/edit/delete.

Additionally, the Object may need to be changed. Currently your record rule is applying on the Users object, when it sounds like you want to apply it on the `account.analytic.line` object so that your rule applies to the Timesheets.

[Record Rules Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/security.html#record-rules)

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Now the last thing I would like to change is so that the employees only can see them self in the User tab. With the rules they couldn't add hours for others but they still see the different employees.

Comment: @SimonGottberg What do you mean by "the User tab"? Can you explain/show which menu or view that is for?

Comment: Well the tab that shows who entering the activity. The user can still se the other employyes but it Will give a error if choosing some1 else.

Comment: Do you want me to attache a screenshot? And do you know how to limit the days a user can add hour to the analytic timeline? What I mean is that I don't want the employees to be able to add more than 5 days old data.

Comment: @SimonGottberg I think it is possible but those are really separate questions, so you should ask new ones.

Comment: Okey, thank you, i got part i originally asked for to work!